# Data theory, json and client applications

Tags: json, client, theory

So, I've been coding web apps for some time now... typically I've done both the data structs and retrieval and the client side coding.  I now have a data admin teammate working with me and his sole job is to return data from a database to an api that serves json; standard stuff.

Recently, I have been having a disagreement with him on how this data should be returned.  Essentially, we have two json objs, the first loaded remotely once (which includes racer name, racer number, etc...) when the application starts.  Secondly, (during the race which is a recurring timed data call) we receive positions incrementally which contains a racer's lat/lon, spd etc.

Where we differ is that he is stating that it is "inefficient" to return the racer name (the first call) in the telem string (the second call).  What this forces me to do is to keep the first data obj in a global obj, and then essentially get the racer's lat/long, spd from the second data obj "on the fly" using a join lookup function, which then returns a new json obj that I populate to a racer grid using jqGrid (looks something like this: getRaceDataByID(json[0].id){//lookup race data by racer id in json[1] where json[1].id == json[0].id[lat/lon, spd] and return new json obj row to populate jqgrid})).

The result seems to be to be an overly-coded/slow client (jquery) application.

My question is about theory.  Of course I understand traditional data structs, normalization, sql etc... But in today world of "webapps" and the idea that it seems that larger web services are going away from "traditional sql" data structures and just returning the data as the client needs.  In this sense, it would mean adding about 3 fields (name, bib number, vehicle type, etc...) to the sql call on each position telem call so I can display the data on the client per the interface's requirement (a data table that display real-time speed, lat/lon, etc...).

So finally, my question: has anyone had to deal with a situation like this and am I "all wet" in thinking that 3 fields per row, in today's world of massive data dependent web applications, that this is not a huge issue to be squabling over.

Please note: I understand that traditionally, you would not want to send more data than you need and that his understanding of data structs and inefficient data transfers (not sending more data than you need) is actually correct.

But, many times when I'm coding a web apps, it's often looked at a bit differently b/c of the stateless nature of the browser, and IMHO and it's much easier to just send the data that is needed. My question, is not being driven by not wanting to code the solution, but rather trying to put less load on the client by not having to re-stitch the json obj into something that I needed in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it makes sense to send these 3 fields with the rest of the data, even if this warrants some sort of duplication. You get the following advantages:

- You don't have to maintain the names of racers from the first call in your browser
- Your coding logic is simplified (don't have to match up racer names to subsequent calls, the packet contains the info. already)

As far as speed goes, you are doing the majority of the work in your remote call, adding another 3 fields doesn't matter IMHO. It makes your app cleaner.

So I guess I agree w/you.

Comment: It would add data to the overall data flow, which adds a little bit of cost.  But we are exclusively working on the Amazon EC2 system and 3 fields of data cost are minimal.  So, I agree with you Sid as well...  Thanks b/c I thought I was going crazy trying to explain this to my teammate.  Unfortunately, I don't think he will change it anyhow, we just keep going in a circle debating this issue...  Thanks for the reassurance at any rate.

Comment: Yes I understand it would add data. Why don't you estimate the number of packets that would go into the EC2 system and figure out the monthly dollar cost of sending 3 strings into EC2 with every request? If it's a few cents a month, I would assume that's insignificant.

Comment: It's definitively a matter of cents or dollars... either way, the money we are spending to have me "code around" this issue is more of a cost than any cost of adding 3 fields.  Every time I have to call the data, I have to re-stitch together the json... which makes the code seem very bloated, not to mention the time it takes the client to parse through all the telem entries.

Comment: The thing that I really wonder as I continue to debate this with my teammate is, what happens to this large dataset that needs to be stitched and rebuilt over time (memory usage, bloating, speed, etc).  Typically, our users will have their browsers open to the same page for 2-3 days watching our events... "look this is a bad idea because handling/looping parsing such a large dataset like this is really going to slow down the browser and become heavy over time, and most likely stop working.

Comment: Depending on how big this DS is, it may also consume a lot of your browser's memory. I guess that depends on how many users you have. 
BTW, thanks for choosing the answer as correct but as you commented on it, it got wiped out.